# PHP: How to get Sunday and Saturday given a date input?

Tags: php, algorithm, datetime

How can I get the Sunday and Saturday of the week given a specific date?

For example:

> input: Monday, September 28, 2009
>
> output should be:
>
> Sunday, September 27, 2009 12:00 AM - Saturday, October 3, 2009 11:59 PM

I am thinking of using the `date`, `strtotime`, `mktime` and `time` php functions.

If you have a usable function then it is also fine with me.

Thanks in advance :)

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You use [`strtotime()`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date()`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
<?php
$s = 'Monday, September 28, 2009';
$time = strtotime($s);
$start = strtotime('last sunday, 12pm', $time);
$end = strtotime('next saturday, 11:59am', $time);
$format = 'l, F j, Y g:i A';
$start_day = date($format, $start);
$end_day = date($format, $end);
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo "Input: $s\nOutput: $start_day - $end_day";
?>
```

outputs:

```
Input: Monday, September 28, 2009
Output: Sunday, September 27, 2009 12:00 PM - Saturday, October 3, 2009 11:59 AM
```

Comment: Thanks for this sir cletus. I think this is much readable and easier to use in my opinion :)

Comment: Thanks sir for the solutions!

Answer (score 9):

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$datetime = new DateTime("2009-09-23 12:00:00");

// Saturday
$datetime->setISODate(2009, $datetime->format("W"), 6);
print "Saturday:" . $datetime->format(DATE_ATOM) . "\n";
// Sunday
$datetime->setISODate(2009, $datetime->format("W"), 0);
print "Sunday: " . $datetime->format(DATE_ATOM) . "\n";


?>
```

Comment: Nice, DateTime is relatively new - no?

Comment: @meder: Available by default as of 5.2, released in late 2006.  It's available on PECL for 5.1.

Answer (score 3):

take a look at [strtotime](http://fr.php.net/strtotime)

i.e.

```
strtotime('next sunday', strtotime($your_date_string));
```

Answer (score 1):

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("last sunday", time()));

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("next saturday", time()));

Answer (score 1):

the issue with the 'correct' answer is, what if the supplied date is Sunday? Then it will give you the previous Sunday, instead of the current Sunday. Same issue with Saturday.

```
$s = 'Monday, September 28, 2009';
$time = strtotime($s);
if(date('D', $time) == "Sun"){
    $start = strtotime(' 12pm', $time);
}
else {
    $start = strtotime('last sunday, 12pm', $time);
}
if(date('D', $time) == "Sat"){
    $start = strtotime(' 12pm', $time);
}
else {
    $start = strtotime('next saturday, 12pm', $time);
}
$format = 'l, F j, Y g:i A';
$start_day = date($format, $start);
$end_day = date($format, $end);
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
echo "Input: $s\nOutput: $start_day - $end_day";
```

Comment: I came here looking for this nuance: My weekend boundaries were wrong, because of what you pointed out (and only saw this while testing on a weekend!).
Is there a reason you're using 12pm day boundaries instead of midnight (12am)?

Comment: Looks like I may have copied and pasted parts of the original answer and made the needed changes. Other than that, at the moment, I can't think of any other reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime

```
$input = strtotime("Monday, September 28, 2009");
$nextSunday = strtotime("next Sunday",$input);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$date = strtotime('Monday, September 28, 2009 - 1 day');
$initialString =  date('l, F d, Y g:i A', $date);
$end = date('l, F d, Y g:i A', strtotime( 'next saturday 11:59 pm', $date));

echo $initialString . ' - ' . $end;
```

output:
Sunday, September 27, 2009 12:00 AM - Saturday, October 03, 2009 11:59 PM

Answer (score 0):

This is what your looking for. It is what I use.

```
$beginningOfWeek = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('last Sunday'));
$endOfWeek = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+6 day', strtotime('last Sunday')) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find my Date Time Helper much handy in this case , it can finish in 3 Lines

http://normandqq.github.io/Date-Time-Helper/

```
    $date = '2013-08-11';
    $monday = Model_DTHpr::getMondayByDate($date);
    $sunday = Model_DTHpr::adjustDays("add",$monday,6);
```

Out Put:

```
    2013-08-05 //Monday
    2013-08-11 //Sunday
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Sunday Php Code:

```
echo "Today Is : " . date("d-m-Y"); 
$dw = date( "w");
$dw = 7-$dw;
echo "\nNext Sunday Is" .date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+$dw days"));
```