# How do I calculate time period blocks in PHP, and determine current one?

Tags: php, datetime, time

We have a service that has people paid out in a rolling two week block timeframe:

- 03-31-13 to 04-13-13
- 04-14-13 to 04-27-13
- 04-28-13 to 05-11-13
- etc

We want to pay people out on dates that would reflect the pay period that ended a week prior:

- 04-20-13 would be the payout date for the time period 03-31-13 to 04-13-13
- 05-04-13 would be the payout date for the time period 04-14-13 to 04-27-13

And so forth

What would be the best way to calculate these time periods and somewhat 'rolling' intervals in PHP? I am no stranger to the `DateTime` class, but I am not quite sure how to approach this.

Basically, the idea is that when a user lands on their billing page, we can tell them what time period they are in, and when they can expect to be paid for the previously ended time period.

**update**

After giving it further thought, it almost seems as though I would need to give it some kind of reference point, to know where to start from. Any ideas?

Thank you.

**UPDATE #2 - My Solution**

```
class PayoutDate {

    const PERIOD_LENGTH     = 14;

    public static $now;
    public static $refStart;

    public static $currentMonth;
    public static $currentYear;

    public static $currPeriodStart;
    public static $currPeriodEnd;

    public static $prevPeriodStart;
    public static $prevPeriodEnd;

    public function initialize(Controller $controller) {

        self::$now                  = new DateTime();

        self::$currentMonth         = self::$now->format('m');
        self::$currentYear          = self::$now->format('Y');

        self::$refStart             = new DateTime("10/20/2013");

    }

    public function getPreviousPeriodStart() {

        $daysIntoCurrentPeriod      = ((int)self::$now->diff(self::$refStart)->format('%a') % self::PERIOD_LENGTH);

        self::$prevPeriodStart      = new DateTime('2 weeks ago');
        self::$prevPeriodStart->sub(new DateInterval('P'.$daysIntoCurrentPeriod.'D'));

        return self::$prevPeriodStart;

    }

    public function getPreviousPeriodEnd() {

        $daysLeftCurrentPeriod      = self::PERIOD_LENGTH - ((int)self::$now->diff(self::$refStart)->format('%a') % self::PERIOD_LENGTH) - 1;

        self::$prevPeriodStart      = new DateTime('2 weeks ago');
        self::$prevPeriodStart->add(new DateInterval('P'.$daysLeftCurrentPeriod.'D'));

        return (self::$prevPeriodStart);

    }

    public function getCurrentPeriodStart() {

        $daysIntoCurrentPeriod      = (int)self::$now->diff(self::$refStart)->format('%a') % self::PERIOD_LENGTH;

        self::$currPeriodStart      = clone self::$now;
        self::$currPeriodStart->sub(new DateInterval('P'.$daysIntoCurrentPeriod.'D'));

        return (self::$currPeriodStart);


    }

    public function getCurrentPeriodEnd() {

        $daysLeftCurrentPeriod      = self::PERIOD_LENGTH - ((int)self::$now->diff(self::$refStart)->format('%a') % self::PERIOD_LENGTH) - 1;

        self::$currPeriodEnd        = clone self::$now;
        self::$currPeriodEnd->add(new DateInterval('P'.$daysLeftCurrentPeriod.'D'));

        return (self::$currPeriodEnd);

    }

    public function getPreviousPeriodPayout() {

        $prevEnd = new DateTime(self::getPreviousPeriodEnd());

        return ($prevEnd->modify('next friday'));

    }

    public function getCurrentPeriodPayout() {

        $currentEnd = new DateTime(self::getCurrentPeriodEnd());

        return ($currentEnd->modify('next friday'));

    }



}
```

I welcome feedback or improvements to this solution :)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.setisodate.php

Comment: i added my solution so others can see how i put it together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think you're right about needing some sort of reference point. I would pick an arbitrary start time of one your pay periods. It doesn't matter if it's in the past or future. You're also going to need a variable representing the length of a pay period. Then it's just a matter of doing some math.

```
$refStart = new DateTime('2013-03-31');
$periodLength = 14;

$now = new DateTime();

// do some modular arithmetic :)
$daysIntoCurrentPeriod = (int)$now->diff($refStart)->format('%a') % $periodLength;
$currentPeriodStart = clone $now;
$currentPeriodStart->sub(new DateInterval('P'.$daysIntoCurrentPeriod.'D'));
```

So after you run that code, `$currentPeriodStart` will store the date of the start of the current pay period. (It won't be accurate down to the second, but the date will be correct.) Then you can just subtract 14 days from it to get the start of the previous period, and add/subtract whatever you need to get the pay day.

This solution has the added benefit of working with daylight savings (which can be annoying) since I'm pretty sure `DateTime` accounts for that.

Comment: this was a tough call, but your response got me closer to the solution that I went with. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using some rules:

- Determinate next Saturday (pay day) of given date and add 1 week

You can do some adjustments for your requirements, hope it helps:

```
<?php
/*
 * Using:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/1485512/496176
 * http://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.add.php
 */
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1W');

$payPeriod1 = new DateTime("2013-04-13");
$payPeriod1
  ->setISODate($payPeriod1->format("Y"), $payPeriod1->format("W"), 6)
  ->add($interval);
print "Pay day: " . $payPeriod1->format('Y-m-d') . "\n"; // Pay day: 2013-04-20

$payPeriod2 = new DateTime("2013-04-27");
$payPeriod2
  ->setISODate($payPeriod2->format("Y"), $payPeriod2->format("W"), 6)
  ->add($interval);
print "Pay day: " . $payPeriod2->format('Y-m-d') . "\n"; // Pay day: 2013-05-04 
?>
```

Comment: That seems like it will work, but how will I use a reference date to calculate the correct offset?

Comment: this is really tough, because my final solution was a hybrid of your answer and jnrbsn's - his got me closer so I accepted his as the final solution. However, I did upvote yours and I implore everyone to upvote both responses!

Comment: I up-voted your question and jnrbsn's answer too. I didn't know `DateTime` function. Is amazing!

Comment: @quantme DateTime isn't a function, it is a class. Sorry to be pedantic, but the difference is important.

Comment: @vascowhite You're not. I had too many hours without sleep. Thanks for the notation.